# Stochastic equation

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory

Let $X,Y$ be Polish spaces and $\kappa:X\times \mathcal B(Y)\to[0,1]$ be a Borel-measurable stochastic kernel on $Y$ given $X$. Under which conditions for a probability measure $\nu$ on $Y$ there exists a measure $\mu$ on $X$ such that $\nu = \mu\kappa$, that is 
$$
  \nu(A) = \int_X\kappa(x,A)\mu(\mathrm dx) \qquad \forall A\in \mathcal B(Y).
$$
In case when $\kappa$ is induced by a Borel map $k:X\to Y$, this equation always has a solution as long as $Y = k(X)$, see e.g. [this paper](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=tvp&paperid=2920&option_lang=eng). I wonder, if anything is known for this general case.

As an obvious counterexample, if $\nu$ is purely atomic and $\kappa(x)$ is atomless for each $x$ there is no solution. Hence, some assumptions are needed to be imposed for the existence. Perhaps something like: for any $A\in \mathcal B(Y)$ there exists $x_-$ and $x_+$ such that $\kappa(x_-,A)\leq\nu(A)\leq \kappa(x_+, A)$. This seems to be equivalent to surjectivity  of $k$ in the special case mentioned above. However, yet again for general case that rules out obvious counterexamples, but likely some combination of atomic and atomless measures still make this condition insufficient.